# How if the last ack is lost in TCP termination?

Tags: sockets, tcp

## Consider this situation:

`A` send a `fin` to `B`, then `B` send a `ack` and a `fin` to `A`. Then `B` goes to state `LAST_ACK`, and `A` goes to state `TIME_WAIT`, and now, what will happen to `B` if the last `ack` from `A` is lost, and the retransmission request from `B` is lost too? Will `B` continue send retransmission request or close socket or else? (We know, if `A` set `SO_LINGER` to 0, when `A` close its socket, it will cause a `RESET` on `B`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as with any data segment. TCP will retry the send a certain number of times and then reset the connection.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. ^_^

Comment: What parameter in kernel set number of retries
And what will happen when number of LAST_ACK state on server is very big, for example 20K ESTA and 60K LAST_ACK?